# How can I use sass class names as it is without using any object webpack sass loader ?

Tags: css, reactjs, sass, webpack, ecmascript-6

I have to use the classNames as like it is like below

```
import style from './style.scss' 

class MyComponent extends Component {

  render() {
    return <button className="my-button">OK</button>;
  }
}
```

usually we are using `style['my-button']` Is it possible to avoid the object style and use like above ?

Comment: @shameerikka, do this `style['my-button']` if you think there will be duplicates of `.my-button` class in other files. Other wise `className="my-button"` is just fine (of course you will have to `import` the file). :)

Comment: @free-soul yathoo  :) I tried this but it is not working.  I think some configuration  is missing in webpack

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just importing file should work fine, but if it doesn't, you have to check your webpack.config - in my case (webpack 2) that's all what I need to deal with sass styles (single rule):

```
  {
    test: /\.scss$/,
    exclude: /node_modules/,
    use: [
      'style-loader',
      'css-loader',
      'sass-loader'
    ]
  }
```

Other way to import styles, if you need only a few classes, is to import them with es2015 syntax:

```
import { greenBck, btnShadow } from '../styles/main.scss';

const MyButton = () => {
  return (
    <button className="btn greenBck btnShadow">GreenButton</button>
  );
}
```

Comment: Yes I checked the webpack configuration. there was `localIdentName` added When I removed this it is working

Answer (score 1):

You can just import the stylesheet:

```
import './style.scss';
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe this webpack config could help you. It allows the use of classes as you are suggesting above.

**Make sure to rebuild after changing your config. We all forget...**

*NOTE:* The code below for the `webpack.config.js` are snippets, so make sure you read my comments.

```
/**
* webpack.config.js
*/

// ADD THE ExtractTextPlugin
var ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin')

// ADD THIS TO YOUR PLUGINS ARRAY
new ExtractTextPlugin('[your-css].css')

// ADD THIS TO YOUR module.loaders ARRAY
{
    // sass -to-> css
    test: /\.scss$/,
    loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract(
        'style', // The backup style loader
        'css?sourceMap!sass?sourceMap'
    )
}
```

---

```
/**
* react file
*/
import style from './[path]/[your-css].css.scss'

... use your classes as normal ...
```

Comment: Also see what @Wayne Ellery has posted - maybe it's a one line fix!